# Reusing/Saving read in arrays of data between runs in C

Tags: c, bash

I am programming in **C** and using bash as my shell. Currently I am trying to optimize when I run my program. The general gist of the program is to input some parameters, read in a data file and then the program runs some calculations based on the input parameters and data from the file. I often run this code 100's of times at a time by only changing the input parameters for each run, and not the data from the file. I do this using a shell script to `xargs` the executable with various parameters.

`printf "%s\n" {0..n} | xargs -P 8 -n 1 ./program`

The problem is I have a very large data file which takes about >1 seconds to read in. This is done at every call to the executable, however, often the data which is read in does not change! Therefore I believe I could save a lot of time by saving this data somehow so that other calls of the executable can use the data that has already been read in, instead of wasting time reading in the data themselves.

I was thinking maybe there could be another program that reads in the data, then protects and sends the address of the data to my current executables. After the executables have finished running in full, this is relayed back to the new program which then releases the data. Is this possible? Or is there another way which would be superior?

Comment: I'd make sure that the data file is optimized for fast reading (i.e. instead of having to process any of it). You could look into using `fork()`, where the parent process reads the data and "automagically" passes it to the child processes. The parent would have to be responsible for calling the child however many times and with the different args.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use shared memory - have one program start at the beginning that reads the data and creates a shared view of it. The other program could map this shared memory in and process it, and unmap it when it's done. Finally, the first process can then free this memory.

Comment: Good question.  No easy answer occurs to me, though I suppose that one could run a daemon which kept the data in a shared memory segment.  Do I infer correctly that your data file takes much longer than 1 second to load the first time you run your program?  That it takes 1 second only after the system has swapped the file into memory?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen:  Your comments suggest a pretty good answer.  If you have some time, why don't you expand the comments and post them as an answer?  (It seems to me that there should be some way to get the filesystem to keep the file in a shared memory segment, but I have never heard of it.)

Comment: There's a way using the `mmap` function in linux, but I'd have to go go look up how to use it.

Comment: In the mean time, http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html might help

Comment: @DrewMcGowen:  You are right about `mmap`, but some process or other still has to load the file into the mapped memory and keep it there, doesn't it?

Comment: That's what the first process would do - you'd run it before running your actual program.

Answer (score 1):

You could try storing the file in shared memory : /dev/shm

Ex: ls > /dev/shm/ls-output

./program < /dev/shm/ls-output

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but something along this line might be helpful I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer to your question, but it would solve your problem if you could only coax the filesystem to keep the file in a shared memory segment, then to publish the pointer and segment identifier needed to access the file in memory.  [See this kernel document,](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand015.html) and [this one,](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt) too.  They may help.

Also, once you have solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer, and also comment below *my* answer so that Stack Overflow flags me to come back here and to look again.